# Rails 3 + Omniauth: undefined method `persisted?' for []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am trying to user omniauth-twitter for my website, but whenever I click on twitter login, I get this error

```
undefined method `persisted?' for []
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb file...

```
def twitter
# You need to implement the method below in your model
@user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Twitter"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

User.rb file...

```
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
data = access_token.extra.raw_info
if user = User.where(:email => data.email)
  user
else # Create a user with a stub password. 
  User.create!(:name => data.name, :email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
end
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

```
user = User.where(:email => data.email).first()
```

Comment: Thank you RadBrad, I removed .first() cuz twitter doesn't give out email for authentication. In my application, email should be unique. Moreoever, there is validates_presence_of email implemented by omniauth gem. Any suggestions?

Comment: The basic problem is the 'where' will return an array of found records. Even if there is only one found,  you'll get array with one record in it.  So the only other approach would be to change @user.presisted? to @user[0].persisted,  or change User.where(:email=> data.email)  to User.find_by_email(),  that will return one User record or nil if the email is not found.